# Is it sinful to give my child the freedom to choose religion by himself?

Tags: halal-haram, other-religions, freedom-of-belief

I want to give my child the freedom to choose religion by his own and want him to have a broad concept of religion. So I want him to study both Quran, Bible, Gita and many other of this kind. Is it sinful for me if I do so? Is it sinful for me if he don't choose Islam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Forenote**: *You said you were a Hindu so this answer is based on if you were Muslim*

---

### Yes, it would be sinful providing that the child's parents were Muslim

---

Allah says in the Qu'ran:

> #### وَمَن يَبْتَغِ غَيْرَ الْإِسْلَامِ دِينًا فَلَن يُقْبَلَ مِنْهُ وَهُوَ فِي الْآخِرَةِ مِنَ الْخَاسِرِينَ
>
> *And whoever desires **other than Islam as religion** - never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers.*
>
> ([Quran 3:85](https://quran.com/3/85))

Therefore, you said you would give your child freedom and if he chooses a religion other than a Islam because you have not brought him up as a Muslim, you would be sinning and so would your child.

I'm aware of verse [2:256](https://quran.com/2/256), which states:

> لَآ إِكْرَاهَ فِى ٱلدِّينِ ۖ قَد تَّبَيَّنَ ٱلرُّشْدُ مِنَ ٱلْغَىِّ ۚ فَمَن يَكْفُرْ  وَيُؤْمِنۢ بِٱللَّهِ فَقَدِ ٱسْتَمْسَكَ بِٱلْعُرْوَةِ ٱلْوُثْقَىٰ لَا ٱنفِصَامَ لَهَا ۗ وَٱللَّهُ سَمِيعٌ عَلِيمٌ
>
> There shall be no coercion/compulsion in matters of faith.

However, according to [Dr. Jasser Auda](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-about-islam/should-i-let-my-children-choose-their-religion/):

> However, there is an “obligation” on every Muslim parent to teach his or her child the religion of Islam. And I am, certainly, not speaking about a certain culture or tradition, in the sense of what people eat, drink, listen to, or wear, even though there are some few Islamic provisions in these areas.
>
> I am speaking about “Islam” in the sense of faith in One God, believing in all the prophets and messengers of God, including Moses, Jesus, and Muhammad (peace be upon them), believing in the Divine Books that God had revealed, including the Torah, Gospel, and Quran, believing in the Afterlife, and the rest of the “pillars of faith” in Islam.

So, if you were a Muslim and you taught your child Islam but he still **doesn't accept** it, the verse [3:85](https://quran.com/3/85) would apply to him.

**And Allah knows best**

Answer (score 1):

Assalam alikum bro Islam said you should guide your child in right and true path.as a world matter you also want to guide your child in prefect filde so you should guide your child in religion's metter and if you are. Muslim then Islam 's say don't leave the right path do research and guide your child which is better for him if you're non Muslim then Islam has not restrictions about you because Islam say do research use logic read Quran then accept islam and give guidis your child about Islam with logic if they are sensible then you have no sin but if they leave Islam because of you then you have sin and Allah know better. ok hope you are understand.  I appreciate your thinking.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](//islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](//islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](//islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).